# Pass array as parameter in macro assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, macros, parameters, x86-16

Is it possible to pass an array as a parameter in macro in assembly? For example,

```
setXY macro temp[0], temp[1]      ; temp is word-sized
   mov ax, temp[0]
   mov bx, temp[1]
```

and somewhere in the body you'll call `setXY coor[0], coor[1]`.

Is it permissible?

Comment: "`setXY coor[0], coor[1]`". You haven't told us what `coor` is, but it looks to me like you want to use elements of the array as arguments, not the array itself. Anyway, an array is just a label specifying the address where the array starts, so it's no different from any other data. You haven't mentioned which assembler you're using, so I don't see how the question can be answered right now.

Comment: `coor` is also a word-sized array. Yes, I want to use the elements inside the array. I'm using TASM assembler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following macro:

```
do_stuff MACRO x, y
  mov ax,[x]
  mov bx,[y]
  add ax,bx
ENDM
```

And an array of words:

```
coor dw 1, 3, 5, 7
```

You could do e.g.:

```
; Use the do_stuff macro with the first two elements of coor as
; the arguments

do_stuff coor, coor+2
```

Which would give you `ax` == `1 + 3` == `4`.